# android error with facebook login on market

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token

When i test this app on my device with eclipse is all ok;but when i publish this app on google play store the facebook login failed!! 
why?
help me please!!
it is a simply app ("coffee break" on market);

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main );

            elementoInserito=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextElementoInserito);
            elementoEstratto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewElementoEstratto);
            inserisci=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonInserisci);
            stampa=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStampa);  

            facebookLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.facebookLogin);
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
             if (session == null) {
                    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                        session =Session.restoreSession(this,null,statusCallback,savedInstanceState);
                    }
                    if (session == null) {
                        session = new Session(this);
                    }
                    Session.setActiveSession(session);
                    if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                       session.openForRead(newSession.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
                    }
                }

                inserisci.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        inizializza_array(elementoInserito);
                        elementoInserito.setText("");
                    }
                });
                updateView();
        } 
        private void updateView() {
              Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
              if (session.isOpened()) {
                facebookLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) { 
                        onClickLogout(); }
                });

              }
             else {
                facebookLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) { 
                        onClickLogin(); }
                });
            }
        } 
        private void onClickLogin() {
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            } else {
                Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
            }
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
           Session.saveSession(session,bundle);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                   "sto salvando la sessione   "+session.getState(),
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        private void onClickLogout() {
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (!session.isClosed()) {
                session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            } 
        }
        private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);    
                updateView();
            }
        }
        private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
            }
        }
        public void inizializza_array(EditText n){
            this.ins=""+n.getText();
            if(ins==""){
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                         "errore: campo vuoto",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                lista.add(ins);
            }
        }
        public void stampa(View v){
            if(lista.size()==0){
                elementoEstratto.setText("Inserire elementi");
            }
            else{
            Random random = new Random();
            String x = lista.get(random.nextInt(lista.size()));
                elementoEstratto.setText(x);
                lista.clear();
               try {
                  publishStory(x);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } 
            }
        }
         public void onStart() {
                super.onStart(); 
                Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
            }  
            @Override
            public void onStop() {
                super.onStop();
                Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
                super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                Session.saveSession(session, outState);
            }
            public void publishStory(String sorteggiato) {
                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                try {       
                if (session != null){  
                    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
                    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                        pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                                .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                        return;
                    }
                    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
                    postParams.putString("name",""));
                    postParams.putString("caption","");
                    postParams.putString("description","");
                    Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                                       .getGraphObject()
                                                       .getInnerJSONObject();
                            String postId = null;
                            try {
                                postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.i(TAG,
                                    "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                            }
                            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                            if (error != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                     error.getErrorMessage(),
                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                       "shared",//postId
                                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                                          HttpMethod.POST, callback);
                    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
                    task.execute();
                    }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "effettua il Login su Facebook per condividere con i tuo amici",
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                }
                private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
                    for (String string : subset) {
                        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
                }    
                @Override 
                        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,Info.class); 
                            //Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Caffe.class);
                            menu.add("About Coffee Break").setIntent(intent);
                            //menu.add("Il caffè").setIcon(R.drawable.caffe).setIntent(intent2);
                           return true; 
                        }       
    }
```

i don't understand why i've this problem

Comment: Did you add the Hash Key of the app's release signing key to your developer account on Facebook? If you haven't, you need to add it along with your debug.keystore Key Hash. If you have added it, then it is wrong and needs to be re-created.

Comment: Have you added the signed keyhash value FB...?

Comment: How to get signed keyhash for fb @Basil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've self resolved the problem, i did not read the relese.keystore in the rigth way
I did not understand this code:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias myAlias -keystore ~/.your/path/release.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

when I realized the code I got the right key

myAlias = alis used when i export the project

~/.your/path/release.keystore = the path where the key generated from eclipse is located, and the name of the file

Good Job