# Facebook Login not working

Tags: android, facebook

Hi I have used facebook login in my android app. It works fine when I build and run it in my device.

Now I uploaded the app to playstore and published it for beta testing. But not the facebook login is not working. I guess the session is not getting opened somehow. I deleted the app and then reinstalled from eclipse. Then its working fine. I am not able to debug as I don't know how to debug a signed release build. Or I guess its not possible. Anyways any similar issues to this happened to you? 
Any work around? Or how to debug?

I am using the Facebook Login button and the rest of the code is below

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            if(!PreferenceHelper.getString(this, "logged_in_status").equals("YES")){
                Log.i("sdf", "Logged in...");
                this.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                      // callback after Graph API response with user object
                      @Override
                      public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                          userInfo = user;
                          userId = user.getId();
                        user_name = user.getName();

                        Handler looper = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                        looper.post(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                            public void run() {
                                  new DownloadFile().execute("http://graph.facebook.com/"+userId+"/picture?type=large");
                              }
                           });
                        try {
                            emailText = user.getInnerJSONObject().getString("email");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                          Log.w("myConsultant", user.getId() + " " + user.getName() + " " + user.getInnerJSONObject());
                      }
                    });
            }
            else{
                this.shareFacebook.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            PreferenceHelper.setString(this, "logged_in_status", "NO");
            PreferenceHelper.setString(this, "facebook_user_id", "");
            PreferenceHelper.setString(this, "user_id","");
            PreferenceHelper.setString(this, "user_name", "");
            Intent a = new Intent(this,MainMenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(a);
            overridePendingTransition  (R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.left_slide_out);
            Log.i("sdf", "Logged out...");
        }
    }
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };
```

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Post relevant code please

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to login on the release build? Also, are you initialising all variables (in debug mode, the compiler sometimes does this for you, but not always in release).

Comment: @JoshuaGerrard This is what happens in release build. I press on login button -> it goes to facebook and asks for permission, comes back but immediately jumps to next activity without performing my code. The main problem I don't know how to debug the release code.

Comment: Have you tried using exceptions? Also, make sure optimization is off and you have your compilers warning level set to maximum

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761218/android-error-with-facebook-login-on-market?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[android error with facebook login on market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761218/android-error-with-facebook-login-on-market?rq=1)

The above post explains it all. The keyhash is different for debug and release versions! :)